# Update function in double F-Bound Polymorphic types

Tags: scala, parametric-polymorphism, self-type

I would like to be able to provide a copy-on-update function in a parametrized, F-Bounded trait, where the value to B updated is also F-Bounded. The traits are as follows:

```
sealed trait A[AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: AA =>
  val data: String
}

sealed trait B[BB <: B[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: BB =>
  val content: AA
}

case class BInst[BB <: B[BB,AA], AA <: A[AA]](content: AA) extends 
     B[BInst[BB, AA], AA]
```

In trait B, I would like to provide a function with the signature

```
def update[NewA <: AA](newA: NewA) : BB[BB, NewA]
```

so that the case class just implements

```
def update[NewA <: AA](newA: NewA) = copy(content = newA)
```

but this doesn't currently compile. What are the correct types for `update` in `B`?

**edit**

An example which should work (but currently doesn't):

```
  class A2Inst extends A[A2Inst] { val data: String = "A2Inst" }
  class A2Inst2 extends A2Inst {override val data: String = "A2INst2" }
  val a1 = new A2Inst
  val a2 = new A2Inst2
  val b = BInst(a1)
  b.update(a2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BB` doesn't take type parameters, just remove them and correct input and return types:

```
sealed trait A[AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: AA =>
  val data: String
}

sealed trait B[BB <: B[BB, AA], AA <: A[AA]] {
  self: BB =>
  def update[NewA <:A[NewA]](newA: NewA) : B[_, NewA]
  val content: AA
}

case class BInst[BB <: B[BB,AA], AA <: A[AA]](content: AA) extends 
     B[BInst[BB, AA], AA] {
  def update[NewA <: A[NewA]](newA: NewA) = copy(content = newA)
}
defined trait A
defined trait B
defined class BInst
```

`NewA <:A[NewA]` should be passed as input to conform `AA <: A[AA]`. It's impossible to return same `BB` with new `NewA`, so your method will return some other `BB`.

Update on your edit1: `A2Inst2` isn't F-bounded, so you can't even `BInst(a1)`, so you should:

```
class A2InstBase[T <: A2InstBase[T]] extends A[T] {val data = "a2Inst"}
class A2Inst extends A2InstBase[A2Inst]
class A2Inst2 extends A2InstBase[A2Inst2]{override val data = "a2Inst2"}
```

Comment: But that just returns the type `B[BB, AA]`, not the new type `B[BB, NewA]`.

Comment: hmm, that still doesn't do the job, as `NewA` does not satisfy the parameter bounds of the case class instance. I have added some test code to the question.

Comment: just `BInst(a2)` also won't work because of your own `AA <: A[AA]` definition, so this is out of F-Bounded types topic

Comment: you are right. I am stuck... I should start a question on subclassing F-Bounded types properly :P

Comment: I've added the solution - it's not related to F-bounded types actually

Comment: hmm, my compiler  does not like the `A[T]` - illegal inheritance. If I make it `A[A2InstBase[T]]`, then the `BInst(new A2Inst)` types do not compile.

Comment: just remove self-type `self: AA =>` from `A`, it will be still F-bounded but not so protected :)